# "If you fed up" vs. "if you are fed up"

Tags: sentence-construction

What's the correct sentence in the below two?

> 1. If you **fed up**, let's call it a day.
> 2. If you **are fed up**, let's call it a day.

Answer (score 3):

'fed up' is a state of mind and therefore 'If you are fed up' is the correct form.

Compare with 'be happy', 'be sad', 'be angry'. Using the same form these would become 'If you are happy ...', 'If you are sad ...', 'If you are angry ...'.

Answer (score 0):

"Fed up" is a predicative adjective; it follows a linking verb and refers back to the subject.  So the second sentence is grammatical.

As for the first one, it doesn't make sense in the sentence.

However, you use the phrasal verb "feed up" in informal BrE; it means to give somebody a lot of food to make them fatter or stronger, for example:

His mother fed him up after his illness.